# Confluence JVM allocates and does not release files

Tags: disk-space-utilization, confluence

Confluence running on Unix was throwing errors about running out of local disk space. With 100GB of space free this should not be possible. A `df -h` showed that 98% of disk space was being used with less than 50MB free. A `du -h /opt/wiki/ | grep G` reported that the wiki was using 31G in total.

With `df` showing that there was very disk space free and `du` showing that the Confluence java application was using a percentage of the disk space it was obvious that the JVM was allocating files and not releasing them.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to restart Confluence.

After the restart the temporary allocated files were freed.

This was probably caused by an excessive use of the [Confluence CLI](https://bobswift.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ACLI)